# computers not visible on network

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares, home-networking, file-sharing

I have two computers only in my home network one has windows 7 and the other has windows 10 both computers dont see each other and I tried everything mentioned [HERE](http://helpdeskgeek.com/networking/cannot-see-other-computers-on-network-in-my-network-places/) but nothing worked please advise

Both computers are connected through wireless network and both access the internet normally.

I disabled firewall on both computers still same result

Comment: Are the 2 devices able to ping each other?

Comment: no both give destination unreachable

Comment: There's not enough information here.  Please edit your question and add details about your network configuration, including output from Ipconfig on each machine. Initial guess: Wireless isolation enabled at the router...?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 you got the problem in one second !! now all the computers see each other, I dont really know what this option in my router do so please post it as an answer to accept....thanks alot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Both computers are connected through wireless network and both access the internet normally.

Assuming your networking is setup properly, and that they are in fact on the same subnet, etc., then my first guess would be that you have wireless isolation turned on in your router.

Wireless Isolation is what it sounds like -- it's an option to isolate wireless clients from each other, and from the wired network (so they can't communicate).  This is a security option.

Answer (score 0):

I've sometimes had to manually add IP addresses for computers to see each other on the network.

On the page you linked, at the step that says "Obtain an IP Address automatically", try selecting "Use the following IP address" and give each computer IPs, e.g. 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2. (Both should have subnet mask of 255.255.255.0). Then try pinging one from the other.